# Why am I getting TypeError: Log.addSales is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am really not sure what is going on here

fnc.js

```
let Log = require('./log.js');

let Func = {};
  
  Func.numGenerator = function () {
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let randNum = (Math.random() * 20);
  Log.addSales(randNum.toFixed(2));
    };
      console.log(Log.totalSales);
  };
  module.exports = Func;
```

log.js

```
let Func = require('./fnc.js');

let Log = {
  _totalSales: [],
  get totalSales() {
    return this._totalSales;
  }, 
  addSales: function(num) {
    this._totalSales.push(num);
  },
};
 module.exports = Log;

Func.numGenerator();
```

why does node log.js return

```
  Log.addSales(randNum.toFixed(2));
      ^
TypeError: Log.addSales is not a function
```

But calling `node fnc.js` with `Func.numGenerator();` at the bottom console logs an array of numbers.

Comment: You changed your whole question in an edit.

Comment: yea i saw your answer after i submitted the edit

Comment: i was trying to make the issue more concise

Answer (score 4):

You have a circular dependency. After running your `let Func = require('./fnc.js');`, you try to require the log.js file `let Log = require('./log.js');`. Node detects that, and to prevent infinite looping, node does not try to import Log again.

When you don't use `Func` inside log.js, no problems occur.

You can see what's happening with a few `console.log`.

Inside `fnc.js`

```
console.log('Exporting Func object');
module.exports = Func;
```

Inside `log.js`

```
console.log('Exporting Log object');
 module.exports = Log;
```

When you run `node fnc.js` you should see

```
node fnc.js 
Exporting Log object
Exporting Func object
```

On the other hand, running `node log.js` should log

```
node log.js 
Exporting Func object
Exporting Log object
```

As you can see, the Func object gets created before the Log object has been exported, leading to it being undefined inside it.

One way to fix it is to remove the require in `log.js` and not use `Func` there. Then keep `fnc.js` the same, and create a third file where you require `fnc.js` and use its `numberGenerator` function.

Comment: could requiring fnc.js and log.js into a third file fix this issue?

Comment: @NormanDavis One way to fix it is to make log.js not require anything. Then, fnc.js require log.js, and lastly, the third file require fnc.js. I will add this to my answer

Comment: im just now starting to really work on creating modularity the original project is a bit of a mess